# Data warehouse rollup and grouping sets, which to use?

Tags: data-warehouse, rollup

I have learned rollup, cube & grouping sets but one thing confuses me is how do I know which to use. For example, if I need to find the sale for each month in 2006 by region & by manager the two queries follow

```
SELECT month, region, sales_mgr, SUM(price)
FROM Sales
WHERE year = 1996
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((month, region),(month, sales_mgr))
```

and

```
SELECT month, region, sales_mgr, SUM(price)
FROM Sales
WHERE year = 1996
GROUP BY ROLLUP(month, region, sales_mgr)
```

I know the result of each one but I don't know which to use to answer the question properly, is there something I missed or are both considered correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ROLLUP` and `CUBE` are just shorthand for two common usages of `GROUPING SETS`.

`GROUPING SETS` gives more precise control of which aggregations you want to calculate.

Comment: oh ok thx but if i get an question like that (as a test) which one do i choose (same question above "find....")